# I want to add pinch and zoom Image editing functionality for xamarin Android Application

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have used "https://github.com/steelkiwi/cropiwa" library for Image editing functionality for xamarin Android Application,
Currently I am struggling with feature where image needs to zoom when touched with in square box which is placed on the image.
Can some one help on this?

Comment: That looks like a native java android library did you bind its AAR?

Answer (score 0):

I used this library for Xamarin.Android to get zoom and editing:
https://github.com/NAXAM/Android-Image-Cropper

Also you feel free to bind any native library.